# Python 3.11; imaplib; Downloading emails; Question Charset

Tags: python, imaplib

Download Email from IMAP with Python and IMAPlib.
I have this code. (look here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrunoFischerGermany/FED-ForensicEmailDownloader/reFactorTryOut/reFactoredVersionTryOut.py)

```
def download_emails(imap: imaplib.IMAP4_SSL, mail_count: int,
                    output_directory: str) -> None:
    output_path = Path(output_directory)
    output_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    print(f"Starting email download to {output_directory}...")

    for i in range(mail_count, 0, -1):
        try:
            _, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
            raw_email = msg[0][1]
            raw_email_string = raw_email.decode("utf-8")
            email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

            with open(output_path / f"{i}.eml", "w") as f:
                f.write(raw_email_string)

            print(f"Downloaded email {i} of {mail_count}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error downloading email {i}: {e}")

    print("Email download complete.")
```

I use this Code for downloading emails as eml.
So emails download creates this errors:

```
Error downloading email 5545: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200a' in position 5837: character maps to <undefined>
byte
Error downloading email 5465: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6115: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 5420: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 5103: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 5365: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 3386: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5361: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6164: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 5359: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5478: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5289: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 5051: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5273: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6857: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5272: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 4567: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 5267: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8073: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5261: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6893: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5233: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5804: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5194: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7467: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5182: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 64611: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 5167: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5874: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5163: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5949: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5128: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7332: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5112: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5522: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5097: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5786: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5091: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6045: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5090: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6029: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 5081: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6773: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 5055: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7277: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4871: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7498: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4859: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6006: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4811: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 5375: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4808: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5950: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4806: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2713' in position 9591: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4805: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5703: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4798: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7461: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4797: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7469: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4765: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 7455: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4739: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ba' in position 5468: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4701: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200c' in position 5182: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4496: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f449' in position 8533: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4461: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2714' in position 6713: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4448: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5483: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4444: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u202f' in position 4834: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4402: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5483: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4375: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5158: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4363: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 14511: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4362: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5550: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4332: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5571: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4263: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4566: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4256: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3604: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4222: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f6c8' in position 9379: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4177: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 16463: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 4171: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4912: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4064: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4156: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4014: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 5195: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 4007: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5795: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4001: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6008: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 4000: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5973: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3978: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5963: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3965: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6002: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3941: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 7439: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3923: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 7505: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3906: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f601' in position 10219: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3905: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f601' in position 9709: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3898: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 124374: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3809: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5434: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3807: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 9302: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3794: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5066: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3770: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u221a' in position 22654: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3572: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4911: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3549: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4656: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3544: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 216568: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3537: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4903: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3529: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6360: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3494: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 3587: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3493: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 3544: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3480: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 6377: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3453: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 74421-74427: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3438: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 10601: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3433: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 10229: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3405: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4879: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3346: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 20019: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3344: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 45188: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3338: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 49947: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3242: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 15752: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3152: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 19783: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3151: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 43367: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3150: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 45179: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3138: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4502: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3125: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 7351: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3113: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 148793: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3107: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5088: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3103: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5192: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3064: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 19788: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3063: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 46819: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3062: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 48634: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 3054: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3370: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3053: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3515: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 3041: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f60f' in position 3677: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2953: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 160624: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2944: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ba' in position 5143: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2923: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 19788: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2920: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 46527: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2918: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 48407: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2847: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 20052: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2824: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f499' in position 6823: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2804: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 139863: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2795: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 100546: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2783: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 85098: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2782: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ba' in position 4550: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2775: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 127151: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2773: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ba' in position 5019: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2692: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 7068: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2689: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 83167: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2662: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 82662: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2629: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3129: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 2520: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 38212: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2517: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 88084: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2511: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 19566: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2507: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u27a4' in position 41024: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2494: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2028' in position 5098: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2418: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 26351: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2377: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1236: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 2352: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 134448: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2338: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 265724: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2320: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 112949: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2318: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b6' in position 4122: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2293: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4974: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 2263: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 51523: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2228: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2015' in position 6330: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2159: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 8781: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2134: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 10894: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2106: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 7206: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2100: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 82696: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2074: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 18237: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2070: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 35163: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 2048: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 30565: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1906: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f60a' in position 4798: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1894: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 136861: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1889: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f609' in position 4668: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1877: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4726: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1796: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3005: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1775: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 74871: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1725: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4831-4832: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1698: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4868-4870: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1615: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 103767: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1612: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b6' in position 4484: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1585: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3184: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1498: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4761: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1258: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 690: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 1212: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 31066: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1192: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 75544: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1185: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3761: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1175: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3530: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1170: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 108663: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1151: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 115552: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 1139: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 2934: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1093: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3007: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1044: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3045: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 1038: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 3878: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 951: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 36073-36074: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 932: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1579878: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 915: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4422: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 913: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1593531: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 909: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1654308: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 904: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1626961: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 896: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1565660: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 888: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4748: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 886: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 4480: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 880: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 1301381: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 792: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 3009: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 781: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3116: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 780: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 17066: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 779: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 13548: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 778: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 16512: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 766: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 2765: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 764: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3119: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 763: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 3120: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 720: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2269-2270: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 548: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1111: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 539: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b6' in position 4193: character maps to <undefined>
Error downloading email 312: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1207: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 231: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 26351-26352: invalid continuation byte
Error downloading email 217: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 2475: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 141: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 2799: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 111: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 2486: invalid start byte
Error downloading email 87: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 449: invalid start byte
```

i want to download all emails of an mailbox...
It is Python 3.11. Imported imaplib

I want to download a mailbox with ~5600 emails.

so i think some thing with the charset?

Comment: It seems the emails are not encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Yes. now i add
```import codecs```
and change the writing line to
```with codecs.open(output_path / f"{i}.eml", "w", encoding='utf-') as f:```
now this error `charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200a' in position 5837: character maps to <undefined>` is gone!